# Is using this Dictionary of KeyValuePair of KeyValuePair less performant than a Dictionary of T?

Tags: c#, performance, list, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I have a need to keep a list and dictionary of Color/float/float triads.  Instead of defining a tiny little class with three properties (`myClass.Color, myClass.FloatValue1, myClass.FloatValue2`), I am instead simply using:

```
List<KeyValuePair<Color, KeyValuePair<float, float>>> myList;
Dictionary<Color,KeyValuePair<float,float>> myDict;
```

and accessing values like:

```
float f = myDict[Color.Red].Key.Key;
float j = myDict[Color.Red].Key.Value;
```

Aside from the slightly weird looking access, am I suffering any performance hit here? Is there any reason to believe that the Dictionary above is less performant than

```
Dictionary<Color,myClass> myDict;
```

or that passing my List above to LINQ queries is less performant than a `List<KeyValuePair<Color,myClass>>` ?

Comment: `Dictionary<KeyValuePair<Color,KeyValuePair<float,float>>` shuldn't compile at all - you're only giving the `Dictionary` a single type argument. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here - just associating two floats with each color? If so, I'd consider either having two collections or a struct to represent the pair of float values. What are they meant to represent anyway? Using `KeyValuePair` when you're not *really* using them in a keyed fashion is not pleasant.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, I'm typing on a computer away from my code. I think you get the picture, tho; instead of creating a class, I'm just using a double KVP pair. And yes, I'm associating the Color with two float vals.

Comment: And are those two float values related? Creating your own struct or class for this feels better than using a KeyValuePair. It's generally a good idea only to ask a question when you're in a suitable place to do so though - putting in code which wouldn't compile isn't a good use of anyone's time, unless you're asking about a compilation failure.

Comment: fixed List and Dict definitions.

Comment: Right. And why do you have a list as well as a dictionary? (Even if you need the list to maintain ordering, is there any reason not to just make it a list of colors, and then look up the color in the dictionary?)

Comment: No ideas on performance?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - the list and the dictionary are in two separate places, unrelated. I keep a list in one place to maintain order, and I use the dictionary in another because I want to directly access and change the value. However, I do see your point.

Comment: I always concentrate on readability before performance. Understanding what you're trying to achieve was my first goal, and it's still not *entirely* clear. Do you have any evidence that performance is actually an issue, or is this purely speculative? I would be asking myself for the most *logical* structure (which isn't using KVP, IMO) before worrying about performance.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek and Jon Skeet: Yeah, I agree. It's legacy code that appears in a LOT of places, so I've been putting off the refactor until after my RC. But before I let it get out the door, I was suddenly terrified that maybe there was a REASON I needed to change it now. It's on the burn down, just low priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference you should be aware of, is that `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is not a class. It's a structure. It means it will act differently when you pass it around. It may not matter, but you should remember that. You should also remember, that `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is immutable, so you can't change it once create. You can just create new one with different key/value.

You should probably reconsider your design. Either introducing your own simple POCO, or using `Tuple<T1, T2>` seems better than usign `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, because **your data does not actually have any key-value relationship**. It's just a set of values you want to handle together. `Tuple` is designed just for that.

Comment: Isn't Tuple also immutable?

Comment: Yes, it is. but it's still better than KVP, because your data does not have key-value relationship.

Comment: So... now that I have fixed the definitions... is there any PERFORMANCE issue I should be concerned about?

Comment: No. I can't see any. Worrying about that without actually seeing any problems seems like a premature optimization.